# overloading non-member conversion to bool operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to write bool-conversion operator for std::bitset

I tried:

```
template<size_t size>
operator bool(std::bitset<size> & b)
{
    return b.any();
}
```

but I got

```
error C2801: 'mynamespace::operator bool' must be a non-static member
```

from my visual-studio.

But when I look up [C2801 explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4fyzf6a.aspx) it says nothing about conversion operators (only about =, ->, [],())

So, is it possible to somehow write "Conversion std::bitset to bool operator?"

(I can not call `b.any()` in my if-statements, because the same code must run when std::bitset is replaced with unsigned or something

```
typedef std::bitset<x> Bitset;
//typedef unsigned Bitset;
```

so the ideal syntax will be like:

```
Bitset b = whatewer;
if(b)
    doStuff();
```

)

If this overloading is not possible, what is the recommended workaround?

so far I use it like:

```
if(b == Bitset(0))
    doStuff();
```

but I dont like it.

Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I do not know of any direct way to do what you suggest.  There may not exist one.  As you know, the trouble is that neither the type converted from nor the type converted to is user-defined.  The compiler does not want to let you add new, implict conversions between types you didn't create.  You may have to define, and to call explicitly, your own function *make_bool().*  At least if you *inline* your function, it should be as efficient at run time as a built-in conversion; but you'll not get implicit conversion, will you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message says, the conversion operator must be a *non-static* member of a class. That is true.

> I can not call b.any() in my if-statements, because the same code must run when std::bitset is replaced with unsigned or something.

If that is your problem, then you can use function overload, and call it passing the argument which will return a boolean value:

```
template<typename T>
bool to_bool(T const & b)
{
    return b; //implicit conversion (if allowed) for all other types
}

template<size_t N>
bool to_bool(std::bitset<N> const & b)
{
    return b.any();
}
```

then use it as:

```
if (to_bool(whatever)) 
{
}
```

It will call the correct overload. If the type of `whatever` is `std::bitset<N>` then the second overloaded function will be called, or else the first one will be called.

Comment: I tried doing this with specialization when all I needed was overload. This seems fine.

Comment: @MarkB: Yes, I saw that you were doing partial specialization of function template which is not allowed.

Comment: @Nawaz thank you very much, this is the best workaround. I can even call it like  `if ((to_bool)(whatever))` to get more casting impression :) thank you once again

Comment: @relaxxx Why would you possibly want to obfuscate the fact that you're calling a function?

Comment: @MarkB I should have used more then one smiley to make clear I am not serious :)

Comment: @relaxxx: Don't do that. `if ((to_bool)(whatever))` might give you casting impression on one hand, but on the other hand, the code becomes really unimpressive. Do not do that.

Answer (score 6):

§12.3.2/1: "A **member** function of a class X with a name of the form [...] specifies a conversion from X to the type specified..." (C++11 uses the same section number and nearly the same wording, adding only that the function takes no parameters).

The other possible way to define a conversion is a constructor (§12.3.1), which is obviously a class member as well.

In short, yes, conversions must always be defined as member functions.

One way to do what you want would be to write a wrapper around `std::bitset` that provides the conversion you care about:

```
template <int size>
class mybitest {
    std::bitset<size> bits;
public:
    operator bool() { return bits.any(); }
}
```

But if you decide to do that, you'll need to write forwarding functions for essentially all the pieces of `bitset` you're using (ctors, assignment, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, your answer is definitely correct, but I will go with Nawaz solution. Your solution is "to much work" but it will give me the syntax I wanted. Once again, thank you

Answer (score 3):

The standard is a bit unclear on this (12.3.2):

> A **member function of a class X** having no parameters with a name of the form [...] specifies a conversion from X to the type specified by the conversion-type-id. Such functions are called conversion functions. No return type can be specified. **If a conversion function is a member function**, the type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is “function taking no parameter returning conversion-type-id”.

The first sentence seems to imply that *only* member functions can be conversion functions, but I'm not sure what the purpose of the conditional "if a conversion function is a member function" is.

I'd take the first sentence as binding and conclude that a conversion function must be a member function.

Answer (score 3):

in case this helps somebody, you can actually provide a not operator instead

```
template<size_t size>
operator !(std::bitset<size> & b)
{
    return !b.any();
}
```

and use it like so using the `!!` idiom:

```
if (!!whatever)
{
}
```

still not ideal, but a bit closer I think.