# There seems to be a contradiction in §12.3.2/1 in the C++11 Standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

C++11 Standard §12.3.2/1 (emphasis mine):

> A **member function** of a class X having no parameters with a name of the form
>
> *conversion-function-id*:
>
> > operator *conversion-type-id*
>
> *conversion-type-id*:
>
> > *type-specifier-seq* conversion-declarator
>
> *conversion-declarator*:
>
> > *ptr-operator conversion-declarator*
>
> specifies a conversion from X to the type specified by the *conversion-type-id*. Such functions are called
>   conversion functions. No return type can be specified. **If a conversion function is a member function**, the
>   type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is “function taking no parameter returning *conversion-type-id*”.

Is a conversion function always a member function, or there are cases where this is not true?

Comment: That's not a contradiction. It is a strange wording, but it doesn't contradict anything.

Comment: It's strange that "conversion functions" is not italicized in the sentence "Such functions are called conversion functions." Is there a primary definition elsewhere in the standard?

Comment: @Casey There is no other definition of *conversion function* (in N3936), it would seem that this *is* the primary definition and hence the term should be italicized in that sentence.

Comment: Related: [overloading non-member conversion to bool operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913834/overloading-non-member-conversion-to-bool-operator)

Comment: The "if" wording was not present in C++98 or C++03. I can find no reference to it in the defect reports list either. It's strange.

Comment: @Casey Did you intend to respond to yourself?

Comment: @izkata Yes. I was answering the question I asked in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Casey Stop talking to yourself - you sound crazy.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The clause "If a conversion function is a member function," was added to the working draft in [N2798](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2798.pdf) as part of the Concepts wording per [N2773 Proposed Wording for Concepts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2773.pdf). N2798 12.3.2/1 reads (I'll use **bold** to show additions, and <strike>strikeout</strike> to show removals):

> <sup>1</sup> A member function of a class `X` **having no parameters, or an associated function of a concept whose sole parameter is of type `X`,** with a name of the form
>
> *conversion-function-id:*
>
> > `operator` *conversion-type-id*
>
> *conversion-type-id:*
>
> > *type-specifier-seq **attribute-specifier<sub>opt</sub>** conversion-declarator<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> *conversion-declarator:*
>
> > *ptr-operator conversion-declarator<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> specifies a conversion from `X` to the type specified by the *conversion-type-id*. Such <strike>member</strike> functions are called conversion functions. <strike>Classes, enumerations, and *typedef-names* shall not be declared in the *type-specifier-seq*. Neither parameter types nor</strike> **No** return type can be specified. **If a conversion function is a member function,
>   t**<strike>T</strike>he type of <strike>a</strike> **the** conversion function (8.3.5) is “function taking no parameter returning *conversion-type-id*”**; if a conversion function is an associated function, the type of the conversion function is “function taking a parameter of type `X` returning *conversion-type-id*”**. A conversion function is never used to convert ...

The Concepts wording was removed in draft [N2960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf). The "If a conversion function is a member function," should have also been removed at that time since it is now vestigal. Pertinent portion of N2960 §12.3.2/1:

> <sup>1</sup> A member function of a class `X` having no parameters, <strike>or an associated function of a concept whose sole parameter is of type X,</strike> with a name of the form
>
> *conversion-function-id:*
>
> > `operator` *conversion-type-id*
>
> *conversion-type-id:*
>
> > *type-specifier-seq attribute-specifier<sub>opt</sub> conversion-declarator<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> *conversion-declarator:*
>
> > *ptr-operator conversion-declarator<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> specifies a conversion from `X` to the type specified by the *conversion-type-id*. Such functions are called conversion functions. No return type can be specified. If a conversion function is a member function, the type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is “function taking no parameter returning *conversion-type-id*”<strike>; if a conversion function is an associated function, the type of the conversion function is “function taking a parameter of type `X` returning *conversion-type-id*”</strike>. ...

**2018-02-03 Update: This has been fixed in C++17**

CWG corrected this wording as a drive-by while fixing [CWG issue 1990](http://wg21.link/cwg1990).

Comment: Impressive answer.  Is there are revision history of the working draft somewhere that lets you find when certain changes were made?

Comment: @VaughnCato I wish. I went to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/ and did a binary search through the years between 03 and 11 to localize the changes.

Comment: @TemplateRex: or `pdftotext` them, add them to a git repo, and `git log -S` them.

Comment: +1 for binary search awesomeness.  A @ninjalj git'd index would be awesome -- blame for the C++ standard!

Comment: I submitted [a pull request to fix this issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/397) in November 2014 since I believe it is editorial. Will report back when/if the pull request is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

A conversion function is always a (non-`static`) member function.

The "if" wording was not present in C++98 or C++03. I can find no reference to it in the defect reports list either. It's strange.

---

As R. Martinho Fernandes [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272181/there-seems-to-be-a-contradiction-in-12-3-2-1-in-the-c11-standard/23273213#comment35616734_23272181) the wording is strange, but not contradictory.